# jQuery is unexpectedly executed in new tab once element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr

I tried to have a navigation slide in on-screen in the viewport after being off-canvas via JQuery when CSS3 Transitions are not supported.

However, what is happening ( once the JQuery event occurs ) is that a new tab is opened that contains the same page where the JQuery is executed.

In other words, when the list-icon is clicked a new tab opened and the navigation slides in in the new tab.
Where I want it to slide in in the current window / tab.

I would greatly appreciate all and any help in achieving this.

Here is a running live example: http://db.tt/GyKXa5NF

Comment: I started a jsfiddle here with your code - http://jsfiddle.net/4sdpZ/1/ - it has jquery and modernizr preloaded in it but since theres no css code I guess the jsfiddle wont work. I cant really tell from just this code without seeing it in demo, perhaps you could try to add the CSS code to the jsfiddle to try and get it working and reproducing the problem you are seeing right on the jsfiddle. To do that add your css there and click "Update" or "Fork" and then comment here when you get it to work.

Comment: I don't know what I did, but I added the CSS to the jsFiddle and tested the fiddle in IE and it worked. Then I tested the page in IE and it worked!

Thank you, i guess, something happened / worked. :-)